# Disabling ARP blocks OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, arp, linux

I am running OpenVPN server on my DD-WRT router at home. When I ssh into a home server, which is running an OpenVPN client behind that home router and disable ARP on it (ip link set dev  arp off, arptables), the server is no more accessible. The SSH tunnel just hangs, no HTTP is served anymore, it doesn't even respond to ping. Why is that? Can it be worked around?

Comment: Thank you for asking; unfortunately this question seems to be about home / consumer networking.  Both home networking and consumer class devices are [off-topic here](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask/).  [su] is the right place to ask this question;  rest assured that several of our members answer there too.

Comment: OK. The question turned out to be wrong anyway - when I got home, I tried to disable it from LAN and it did the same thing, without OpenVPN in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ARP is what is needed at the link layer of your network to find your server, so you have to keep it on. ARP is used to resolve an IP adresse to a MAC address on the local network.

Edit by OP: the reason was really ARP, but the fact the server's ARP cache was being flushed right away.

Comment: Nope. The SSH tunnel hangs right away, there's no delay. For ARP there's a cache so that would not clear right away. Also, it only affected me, not the other person who was working with the server normally.

Comment: When disabling ARP, the ARP cache is flushed ... And what's the point in trying to debug a break in a connection after disabling the essential part of it ... you should disconnect the network cable of your server, unplug the power and wonder why it doesn't answer at all ...